# CQL query: Geoserver 2.5.2 CQL BBOX filter

Tags: cql, geoserver

Trying to use CQL bounding box filter, but get a strange result like this:

```
loadFeatures({"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":15640,"features":[]})
```

as it is 15640 features in that bbox, but why there are no list of them and features are just empty list.

my request is following:

```
http://loom-gis.geo.ut.ee:8080/geoserver/ermas/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ermas:testdata_geopnt&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures&maxFeatures=50&srsname=EPSG:3301&EPSG:3301&CQL_FILTER=%28BBOX%28geometry,494981.10875,%206437855.3625,%20684824.8587499999,%206569105.3625%29%29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wfs version 1.0.0

this request :

http://loom-gis.geo.ut.ee:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ermas:testdata_geopnt&srsname=EPSG:3301&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures&CQL_FILTER=%28BBOX%28geometry,494981.10875,%206437855.3625,%20684824.8587499999,%206569105.3625%29%29